# Rank the row based on the similar sentences using python or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, search, sentence-similarity

How to rank the data frame based on the row value. i.e I have a row that contains text data want to provide the rank based on the similarity? Below is the sample datasets,the original datasets contain around 100000 records. Kindly refer this question for [Sort sentence matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251125/rank-the-row-based-on-the-similar-text-using-python)

[image]

There are some methods are tested to cluster the similar sentences small datasets please the refer the above attached link . Output we need to cluster the similar sentences irrespective the length.

Example - To match sentence using python , thanks to [laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11246056/laurent). The below code works well if the sentence length is less

```
df = (
    df
    .assign(
        match=df["text"].map(
            lambda x: [
                i
                for i, text in enumerate(df["text"])
                if textdistance.jaro_winkler(x, text) >= 0.9
            ]
        )
    )
    .sort_values(by="match")
    .drop(columns="match")
)
```

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images.

Comment: code is updated, table i will try to provide @Serg

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import textdistance

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "name": [
            "alexander szelle",
            "al futtain stroes llic",
            "irca middle east llc",
            "giga real estate",
            "mr marwan mohad ibrahim al abdulla",
            "knowledge management human resource consul",
            "yaaqoub hamdan foodstuff trading co llc",
            "grand star contracting llc",
            "middle east llc",
            "marwan mohad ibrahim",
        ],
    }
)

df = (
    df.assign(
        match=df["name"].map(
            lambda x: max(
                [textdistance.jaro_winkler(x, text) for text in df["name"]],
                key=lambda x: x if x != 1 else 0,
            )
        )
    )
    .sort_values(by="match")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(df)
# Output
   id                                        name     match
0   6  knowledge management human resource consul  0.615140
1   4                            giga real estate  0.638258
2   1                            alexander szelle  0.654924
3   7     yaaqoub hamdan foodstuff trading co llc  0.660684
4   8                  grand star contracting llc  0.660684
5   2                      al futtain stroes llic  0.670047
6   5          mr marwan mohad ibrahim al abdulla  0.741471
7  10                        marwan mohad ibrahim  0.741471
8   3                        irca middle east llc  0.805556
9   9                             middle east llc  0.805556
```

Comment: Thank you @laurent - clarification the two match score is working here i.e id 6 and red 4 match is 61 and 63 ? Could you please tell